# Recover from fatal error in excel VBA Workbook_Open?

Tags: excel, excel-2003, xla, vba

I stumbled on a way to crash excel in `Workbook_Open` while making an `.xla`  It's still a toy project, so I've been able to just delete it and start over (and now I'm coming back with version control and baby steps.)

However, assuming I didn't have those options, how would I possibly edit the .xla remove the fatal code, since I have to load it to edit, and loading it crashes the editing environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you are looking for. But some advice during development.

I always work on my xla files as xls files until they are stable. That way if it isn't stable, I can just not enable macros on opening, and fix the problem, then close and reopen with macros enabled.

--EDIT--

I did some more research, because I was curious and because I remembered hearing about disabling macros on startup. Here is a link that says you can hold 'Ctrl' while Excel is starting, to start in Safe Mode. There is a bit of other information that is worth a read to see if it applies.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826922

--EDIT 2--
Another link that says holding 'Shift' might also do the trick

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=348351

Comment: Not perfect because it requires forethought, but definitely a good tip.